# When using a roaming user profile, where can the registry keys for the profile be located on the remote server?

Tags: roaming

By default, if a user account is configured to use a Roaming profile, several locations relating to the profile are copied to a file share whenever that user logs off. One of these items that is included as part of the sync process includes the user's local registry keys. If taking a look at the data for the user's roaming profile on the file share on the server, where can registry data for the profile be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is ntuser.dat and it located in the root of the user profile. You will have to view hidden files.

Comment: I'm on 2008 R2, and it looks like this is ntuser.ini? Is this correct?